# Understanding sentence (until far more recently than the 3.5bn years ago)

Tags: phrases, expressions, sentence

Could you please explain the highlighted part of the sentence below? Thanks!

Researchers hope rocks collected here will confirm that volcanic activity on the Moon continued `until far more recently than the 3.5bn years ago` that is the estimate derived from studies of currently available samples.

Source: https://www.economist.com/science-and-technology/2020/11/21/china-plans-to-bring-back-the-first-moon-rocks-for-40-years

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use "the"? (than the 3.5bn years ago)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/552672/why-use-the-than-the-3-5bn-years-ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current studies estimate that volcanic activity ceased on the moon 3.5 billion years ago.

Researchers hope that the new samples will show that previous estimate to be wrong. They hope to show that  volcanic activity continued beyond that previous estimate.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks! 
Why  has **the** been used before 3.5bn?

Comment: @Budu Gulo - You're welcome. The use of "the" isn't necessarily easy to answer. I think it deserves a separate question. I suggest you post a new question about just this aspect of the sentence.

Comment: I have just posted a separate question. See <https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/552672/why-use-the-than-the-3-5bn-years-ago>. Thanks!